# Extending an object with .call() and .apply()

Tags: javascript

If I have this basic structure

```
var Foo = function(str) 
{
    console.log('Object string: ' + this.str);
    console.log('Param string : ' + str);
}

var Bar = function()
{
    this.str = 'object string';
}

var obj = new Bar();

Foo.call(obj, 'param string');
```

It's fairly obvious what .call() is doing in context. I recently came across some articles that went into depth on abstracting the .call() function. The premise is along these lines (this code is verging on pseudo code as I have stripped it down for ease of reading) :

```
var Extension = {
    // Fire a callback in global scope
    fireCallback : function(event, args) {
        this.callbacks[event].apply(window, args);
    },

    // Attach a callback
    addCallback : function(event, fn) {
        this.callbacks[event].push(fn);
    },

    // Now the bit that I really can't wrap my head around
    enable : function() {
        var self = this;

        if ( ! self.callbacks ) {
            self.callbacks = {};
        }

        self.fireCallback = function(event, args) {
            Extension.fireCallback.call(self, event, args);
        };

        self.addCallback = function(event, fn) {
            Extension.addCallback.call(self, event, fn);
        };
    }
}
```

There is some form of JS voodoo going on here that I can't programatically work out, can anyone help me shed light on how JS is interpreting this and why when I call:

```
Extension.enable.call(this);
```

within a class scope, the Extension object seems to extend the calling objects prototypes allowing me to bind a callback within the class scope. And then attach a handler after I have instantiated the class.

```
function Bar() {
    Extension.enable.call(this);

    // Do stuff

    this.fnCallback = function()
    {
        this.fireEvent('complete');
    }
}

var bar = new Bar();

bar.addCallback('complete', function(args)
{
    console.log('complete');
});

bar.fnCallback(); // logs 'complete' to console
```

The logic is really confusing me, I understand how call() and apply() work in the simple example above but I have no idea how or why the prototypes of the object are extended when I call `Extension.enable.call(this);`.

Could anyone help me shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flambino has it mostly right, my explanation may help or hinder. Anyhow, here goes.

```
> var Foo = function(str)
```

I don't know why you are using a function expression, a declaration seems more suitable:

```
function Foo(str) {
```

.

> var obj = new Bar();
>
> Foo.call(obj, 'param string');
>
> It's fairly obvious what .call() is doing in context

Perhaps, but unless you say what **you** think is going on, we can't know if your understanding is correct. And while the mechanics are fairly straight forward, it is more important to know what you are trying to do.

Such explanations are important to confirm that you and others are thinking the same thing.

> ... can anyone help me shed light on how JS is interpreting this and why when I call:
>
> Extension.enable.call(this);
>
> within a class scope,

I would say "from within the constructor", as javascript doesn't have classes and only function's have scope (and constructors called with `new` can only create plain objects).

> Extension object seems to extend the calling objects prototypes

Not the prototype but the object itself, see below.

> ... allowing me to bind a callback within the class scope. And then
>   attach a handler after I have instantiated the class.
>
> function Bar() {
>       Extension.enable.call(this);

The `enable` function is called as a plain function with its `this` set to the new instance of Bar. So `enable` is adding properties ("extending") the instance itself, not its `[[Prototype]]` (which is `Bar.prorotype`).

```
>     this.fnCallback = function() {
>         this.fireEvent('complete');
>     }
> }
```

That also extends the instance (i.e. there is now `bar.fnCallback` property). And I think `fireEvent` should be `fireCallback`.

```
> var bar = new Bar();
>
> bar.addCallback('complete', function(args)  {
>     console.log('complete');
> });
```

That is calling the `addCallback` method of `bar`, so `this` within the function is `bar`. It rather circuitously adds a member to `bar.callbacks` with a name of `complete` and value of the provided function, effectively:

```
bar.callbacks['complete'] = function(args){...}; 

>
> bar.fnCallback(); // logs 'complete' to console
```

So that calls `fnCallback` with `bar` as `this`. That function calls `bar.fireEvent`, passing it the parameter `'complete'` and setting its `this` to `bar`.

I've assumed `fireEvent` should be `fireCallback` (since `fireEvent` isn't defined).

Anyhow, it calls

```
Extension.fireCallback.call(self, event, args);
```

where `self` is `bar`, which ultimately calls (replacing `this` with `bar`):

```
bar.callbacks['complete'].apply(window, args);
```

So the prototype isn't invovled at all (unless I'm wrong about `fireEvent`). Setting `this` to `window` within the callback doesn't do anything in this case since it isn't used.

Within the function, `console` will be resolved on the scope chain, probably being found on the global object (`window.console` in a browser), then it's `log` property will be called, writing `'complete'` to the console.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the answer rob, to clear it up, I do understand how call and apply work, the question was more aimed at how the object could be bound to another objects context with a call to it's own method from within that context. Very informative answer mind you and did help me considerably. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but I'll have a go at answering. If I'm completely off, let me know.

Technically, no prototypes are being extended, only the instance is being extended. In your last example, the `Bar` constructor (aka "class") does not have any of the callback functions in its prototype. However, since `Bar` invokes `enable` when being instantiated, any instance of `Bar` will always be extended at runtime.

If you have code like

```
var Extension = {
  enable: function () {
    // Here, "this" === Extension, unless overridden by call/apply
    this.sayHi = function () {
      // Here, "this" === (whatever "this" is above)
      console.log(this.text);
    };
  }
};

function Foo() {
  // Here, when instantiating, "this" will be a new instance of Foo.
  Extension.enable.call(this);
  this.text = "Hello, world";
}

var instance = new Foo;
instance.sayHi(); // logs "Hello, world"
```

it's equivalent to

```
function Foo() {
  // Here, "this" === instance of Foo
  this.sayHi = function () {
    // Here, "this" === (whatever "this" is above)
    console.log(this.text);
  };

  this.text = "Hello, world";
}

var instance = new Foo;
instance.sayHi(); // logs "Hello, world"
```

Said another way:
You have function *F* (`enable` in this case) in which `this` would normally refer to the object of which *F* is a property (`Extension` in this case).
Then you have constructor, *C*. When you instantiate *C*, the constructor's `this` refers to a new instance of *C*. Within that constructor - by using `call()`- *F* is invoked as though *F* is a property of that same *C*-instance.
So when *F* is invoked, its `this` refers to the instance of *C*. Thus, whatever *F* does to `this`, will be done to the *C* instance.

In your case, `enable` adds a few methods to `this`, so in effect it's adding those methods to the instance of `Bar`. In other words, if you start at the call to `enable` in the `Bar` construtor, just read through all the code in and every time you see `this` think of it as `bar`.

But note again, that all this is taking place on instances; not prototypes. It's just that since you can only get an instance by invoking the constructor, and the constructor immediately extends the instance, the extra methods seem as though they're prototypal.

I hope that made even the slightest sense - it really is pretty hard to explain.

Comment: You explanation seems to misconstrue scope. There is no scope issue here, only a misundertanding of objects and properties.

Comment: @RobG Yeah, you're right - I'll revise my answer.

Comment: Apologies for the very late follow up to your answer! This did go someway to helping em understand what was going on, it is much clearer how this all fits together now thanks to this and RobG's answer.